Spring Jpa findById causes StackOverflowError but other queries have no problem
I have an entity named Track associated with my Source Entity. If there is data in my Track Entity and it is associated with Source, I cannot use findById or findAll queries in the Source Repository and I get an error as follows
i get this error :
Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError\] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Track.toString(Track.java:7) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4220) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) \~\[na:na\] at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:585) \~\[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final\] at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) \~\[na:na\] at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Source.toString(Source.java:9) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) \~\[na:na\] at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Track.toString(Track.java:7) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4220) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) \~\[na:na\] at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:585) \~\[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final\] at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) \~\[na:na\] at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Source.toString(Source.java:9) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) \~\[na:na\] at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Track.toString(Track.java:7) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4220) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) \~\[na:na\] at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:585) \~\[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final\] at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) \~\[na:na\] at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Source.toString(Source.java:9) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) \~\[na:na\] at com.encode.atlas.encoder.entity.track.Track.toString(Track.java:7) \~\[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\] at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4220) \~\[na:na\]

My Source Entity :
@Data

@Entity

public class Source {


@Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;

private String name;

private String path;

private Integer duration;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

private List\<Track\> tracks = new ArrayList\<\>();

}

My Track Entity :
@Data

@Entity

public class Track {

@Id

@GeneratedValue

(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

@JsonBackReference

private Source source;

private Integer index;

private String codecType;

private String pixelFormat;

private Integer width;

private Integer height;

private Integer bitrate;

private Double fps;

private String codec;

private Integer sampleRate;

private String channel;

}

query =
`Source source = sourceRepository.findById(job.getSource().getId()).orElseThrow();`
I am using java 17 and spring 3.0.7 versions
I already tried to use FetchType.LAZY and FetchType.EAGER also @JsonBackReference  but it didn't work.

Don't use @Data with @Entity it is a bad idea for multiple reasons. https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ for more info.

You are using Lombok Data annotation that will generate equals/hashCode/toString, and because you have a bi-directional relationship, this will cause a StackOverFlowError. One of those methods is called.
You have to break this cycle with Lombok. For toString you can use
@ToString.Exclude

to exclude one of the sides of the cycle.
IMO you shouldn't use @Data with JPA because the generated equals/hashCode methods are not correct.
Read more here:
https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/
